# Old corner and new Tzitzit

Tags: halacha, tzitzis

I wanted to reformulate [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69349/9215), but my idea is a bit different and I decided to ask it independently.

#### The case:

A very big talit corner which is sufficient to be itself a talit is detached. He has already a tsitsit which was a part of mitsva for the formrr big talit.

#### The question:

When I make the new little talit, can I conserve this tsitsit snd add nor 3 tsitsiot? Or need I make it new because it was not made for this new garement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  Shulchan Aruch Orach Chayim siman 15 sayf 3:

> טלית מצוייצת כהלכתה שחלקוה לשתים ובכל חלק יש בו שיעור להתעטף ונשאר לכל אחת מהם ציצית אחת או שתים אין בו משום תעשה ולא מן העשוי: ‏
>
> A talit with regular tsitsiot,  which has been separated into two parts,  each part has a sufficient size to be a regular  talit (size for wrapping), each part has one or two tsitsiot from the old talith. This already made tsitsiot are regular,  no problem of taasse velo min haassui.

**Tsitsiot can be conserved.**

The reason is that great corners are not annulled from the duty of tsitsit.

Some poskim allows even to stitch the two parts together, or to add a new piece.

---

Sources:
1. Gemara Menachot 41a:

> טלית שנקרעה חוץ לשלש יתפור תוך שלש לא יתפור תניא נמי הכי טלית שנקרעה חוץ לשלש יתפור תוך שלש רבי מאיר אומר לא יתפור וחכ"א יתפור ושוין שלא יביא אפילו אמה על אמה ממקום אחר ובה תכלת ותולה בה ושוין שמביא תכלת ממקום אחר ותולה בה דף מא,ב  ובלבד שלא תהא מופסקת